# Is there a possible way to login users from one website to another website?

Tags: security, authentication, authorization, credentials

Let's say there's a website A where I have permission to manage accounts and credentials in order to give access to other users, and i want to limit users to 2 different devices at maximum(one mobile, one laptop/desktop); but I don't own A so I can't  modify or even view the source code.

I was wondering if it was possible to create a website B where I store server-side the credentials of website A, and give users credentials of website B instead, verify the restrictions there, and redirect them to A already logged in.

Comment: Did you see OpenID?

Comment: Didn't know about OpenID and i just searched about it. If I understood correctly, it seems that OpenID requires website A to accept OpenID as authentication, but since  A doesn't accept this, this option would work in my case.